# Laravel Array Value not store into database

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store array data but its giving me null value, I dont know what happend. Bellow the responses and my trial code:

Reponse Data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => facebook
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => facebook
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [icon] => facebook
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => linkedin
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [url] => linkedin
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [icon] => linkedin
        )

)
```

Controller:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($request->fields); $i++) {
            $socialitem[] = [
                'name'      =>  $request->fields['name'][$i],
                'url'       =>  $request->fields['url'][$i],
                'icon'      =>  $request->fields['icon'][$i],
                'teams_id'  =>  $team->id,
            ];
        }

        TeamsSocial_link::insert($socialitem);
```

My table:

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('url');
    $table->string('icon')->nullable();
    $table->bigInteger('teams_id')->unsigned();
```

I have try above code to store array data but its not working, I also research interet and try that way but still getting error.

Comment: That *"Reponse Data"*, is it the whole data you're working with or just a sample of one item inside the *actual* data ?

Comment: its just sample data, I have repeater form, where i can add user social media link and url. So one user can be multiple social media account.

Comment: Show your TeamsSocial_link model

Comment: namespace App\Models\Backend;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TeamsSocial_link extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'url', 'icon', 'teams_id'
    ];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me like you should do something like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->fields); $i++) {
        $socialitem = [
            'name'      =>  $request->fields[$i]['name'],
            'url'       =>  $request->fields[$i]['url'],
            'icon'      =>  $request->fields[$i]['icon'],
            'teams_id'  =>  $team->id,
        ];

        TeamsSocial_link::insert($socialitem);
    }
```

if you need only one item, no need for the loop

```
        $socialitem = [
            'name'      =>  $request->fields[0]['name'],
            'url'       =>  $request->fields[1]['url'],
            'icon'      =>  $request->fields[2]['icon'],
            'teams_id'  =>  $team->id,
        ];
```

if you want to have multiple items

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->fields) / 3; $i = $i+3) {
        $socialitem = [
            'name'      =>  $request->fields[$i]['name'],
            'url'       =>  $request->fields[$i+1]['url'],
            'icon'      =>  $request->fields[$i+2]['icon'],
            'teams_id'  =>  $team->id,
        ];

        TeamsSocial_link::insert($socialitem);
    }
```

Comment: its say : 
"Undefined array key \"url\""

Comment: you don't need the loop, just do

 `$socialitem = [
            'name'      =>  $request->fields[0]['name'],
            'url'       =>  $request->fields[1]['url'],
            'icon'      =>  $request->fields[2]['icon'],
            'teams_id'  =>  $team->id,
        ];`

Comment: But i have repeater field data to store, your code look like store only one time.

Comment: Ok let me try on it

Comment: Awesome, Now working but its store only two data, when i have added 4 repeater, i got store 2 only.